# electron/nodejs read shortcut file (lnk)

Tags: node.js, electron, filesystems, shortcut

im trying to write an electron app that can read and store shortcut files.

I was using `electron.shell.readShortcutLink` to read shortcut information.

```
var shortcut = shell.readShortcutLink(pathToShortcut);
console.log(shortcut);
```

However this does not work on all shortcuts, its throws exeprion when trying to read some shortcuts like :

```
vscode
steam games
microsoft edge
```

and probably more.

So I tried to read those shortcuts with nodejs file system with `fs.readFileSync`, and i apperantly can read some data, but i cannot convert it to string.

```
var shortcut = fs.readFileSync(pathToShortcut);
console.log(shortcut);
//<Buffer 4c 00 00 00 01 14 02 00 00 00 00 00 c0 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 9b 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 02 f0 7d ff 0c 30 d5 01 af a6 de b2 0d 30 d5 01 19 0c 09 3e 4e 0c ... 950 more bytes>
console.log(shortcut.toString());
//does not print anything
```

i found out that i schould be able to convert the bytes from the Buffer to string by calling `.toString()` on it. However when i try to `console.log` the outcome, nothing gets printed.

My question is, how can i read all the Shortcuts? is there any working libary for that? (i couldn't find any)

i did read other questions on stackoverflow but there was nothing working in my situation.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?